# is k-means ++ suitable for large data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, bigdata, cluster-analysis, k-means

I used this k-means++ python code for initializing k centers but it is very long for large data, for example 400000 points of 2 dimension:

```
class KPlusPlus(KMeans):
def _dist_from_centers(self):
    cent = self.mu
    X = self.X
    D2 = np.array([min([np.linalg.norm(x-c)**2 for c in cent]) for x in X])
    self.D2 = D2

def _choose_next_center(self):
    self.probs = self.D2/self.D2.sum()
    self.cumprobs = self.probs.cumsum()
    r = random.random()
    ind = np.where(self.cumprobs >= r)[0][0]
    return(self.X[ind])

def init_centers(self):
    self.mu = random.sample(self.X, 1)
    while len(self.mu) < self.K:
        self._dist_from_centers()
        self.mu.append(self._choose_next_center())

def plot_init_centers(self):
    X = self.X
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.xlim(-1,1)
    plt.ylim(-1,1)
    plt.plot(zip(*X)[0], zip(*X)[1], '.', alpha=0.5)
    plt.plot(zip(*self.mu)[0], zip(*self.mu)[1], 'ro')
    plt.savefig('kpp_init_N%s_K%s.png' % (str(self.N),str(self.K)), \
                bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
```

Is there a way to speed up k-means++?

Comment: Take a look at Mini-Batch K-Means. At each iterations, it randomly selects a subset of your input data to update the centroids using gradients.

Answer (score 2):

Initial seeding has a large impact on k-means execution time. In [this post](http://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/improved-seeding-for-clustering-with-k-means/) you can find some strategies to speed it up.

Perhaps, you could consider to use the [Siddhesh Khandelwal's K-means variant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04600), which was publised in Proceedings of European Conference on Information Retrieval (ECIR 2017).
Siddhesh provided the python implementation [in GitHub](https://github.com/siddheshk/Faster-Kmeans), and it is accompanied by some other previous heuristic algorithms.

Comment: That code is so bad, any conclusions drawn from it are likely wrong because of the huge overheads by the naive code.

Comment: Benchmark it yourself against R and sklearn and ELKI and the good implementations by Greg Hamerly at https://github.com/BaylorCS/baylorml and you will be surprised by the huge difference. Which doesn't of course mean their idea doesn't work, but their experiments at least are worthless.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you didn't give us informations about the huge overheads caused by this code. Which overheads you talk about?

Comment: The point objects, nothing being vectorized etc. Just **benchmark** if you don't trust me. Get a million points data set, and measure the runtime to convergence with tolerance 0.

Answer (score 2):

K-means++ initialization takes O(n*k) to run. This is reasonably fast for small k and large n, but if you choose k too large, it will take some time. It is about as expensive as one iteration of the (slow) Lloyd variant, so it will usually pay off to use kmeans++.

Your implementation is worse, at least O(n*k²) because it performs unnecessary recomputations. And it probably always chooses the same point as next center.

Note that you also only have the initialization, not the actual kmeans yet.

Comment: Thank you. The code is from [this post](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/improved-seeding-for-clustering-with-k-means/), there are kmeans and kmeans++. It does work but it is very long. I need of the good seedings to have a correct clustering. And k-means++ return the good seedings but its execution is so long.  Which recomputations it performs?

Comment: It's even in the comment section of that post... Don't use code from random blogs, it usually has issues. Why don't you just use the sklearn version?

Comment: In particular, don't expect random blog post snippets in a slow scripting language to be scalable or correct...

Comment: As part of my work, I need to modify Lloyd k-means. Sklearn doesn't provide clear k-means code. So it's difficult to reuse their code.

Comment: Lloyd is a very slow algorithm. Why start with the slowest variant if you seem to have largish data?

Comment: Which recomputations Lloyd k-means performs? Do you suggest which variant to modify? As part of my research work, I need to modify an clustering or classification algorithm in order to improve their execution time. The improvement consists of pre-calculating before the algorithm execution the values that will be used by that algorithm. These values are normally calculated by that algorithm during its execution.

Comment: It recomputes the same distances O(k) times. But that is just because of the bad code you got from the blog. The real kmeans++ doesn't do that. You see: for your assignment you need to use a *good* code. You want to improve an algorithm, not fix a bug in a bad blog post.

Comment: Have a look at the one linked above. Also, the better k-means variants cannot benefit from precomputing distances: they never use the same distance twice.

Comment: Have you a proof that k-means variants never precompute the distances twice or means twice?

Comment: Well, Lloyd's algorithm (the slow one) may compute some distances unnecessarily at the end, when some clusters no longer change, but others still change. But the better algorithms recognize this, and skip those clusters.

Comment: But before partial convergence, the chance of a cluster mean being exactly the same as in an earlier iteration is pretty much 0.

Comment: Do you have sources of research articles or papers that report your assumptions?

Comment: No. It's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run any experiment yet, but Scalable K-Means++ seems rather good for very large data sets (perhaps for those even larger than what you describe). 
You can find the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.6402) and another post explaining it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135656/k-means-a-k-a-scalable-k-means).

Unfortunately, I haven't seen any code around I'd trust...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it's called also kmeans||. The second link doesn't work.

Comment: thank you. What's differ algorithmically k-means++ from scalable k-means++?